# Rename a committed branch

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

how to rename a committed branch in tortoise Hg workbench?
[image]

Comment: Have the changesets on the branch been pushed somewhere or are they still in the draft phase?

Comment: Pushed to remote repository.

Comment: Well, then I wouldn't do it. The name of the branch is encoded into each changeset in such a way that your only way to rename a branch is to essentially create new changesets for those involved (and all those that follows). This will make it a major headache getting everybody synchronized again and to avoid a stray push from an old repository to suddenly bring back all the changesets with the old name. If you **really** want to or need to go down this route there are several ways, but `hg convert` is probably the most straightforward. Just make sure you nuke any and all clones and forks.